# Python script can't write file

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app hosted on a Linode server. I have a script to fetch a json and write it to a file. When I run this script `getprice.py` on my server I get the error `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'app/static/prices.json`. It works fine on my local machine though. What do I have to do to get it working?

Comment: could you please provide the exact command sequence you are executing and the code that is being executed?

Comment: Not sure who upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. The user your script is running as on the server doesn't have write permissions on 'app/static'. It may be helpful if you also posted the getprice.py code, but it seems like a pretty straightforward file permission problem.